# Optimizing Customer Request Classification: Handling Multilabel Notes and Varied Description Lengths

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, supervised-learning

I'm working on a project to classify customer requests based on a dataset that includes request descriptions, labels and sentiments. The goal is to predict the label (and sentiments) of customer requests (using a supervised algorithm).

Here's an example of my dataset:

| descriptions | labels | sentiments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer requests information on the new energy tariff. | energy_tariff | neutral |
| Customer reports technical problems with the electrical system, urgent intervention required. | technical_issue | negative |
| Confirmation of the termination of the contract for customer XYZ. | contract_termination | neutral |
| Spoke with XY. Requested update of contact channel in paper mode. However, facing difficulties on the system as the corresponding section in the customer card does not display the desired option. Despite attempts to refresh and restart the system. Kindly proceed with updating the paper contact channel for the contract. | contact_channel_update; system_issues | neutral |

My dataset consists of 3 million observations.

**Problem Description:**
Customer requests vary in description length, ranging from very concise to quite extensive. They are classified into various labels such as "cessation," "credit," "renewal," etc. One additional challenge is that a single note can have multiple labels associated with it.

**What I Have Tried So Far:**
I have tokenized the descriptions and used a BERT-based model. However, I am exploring other options as I am facing some performance challenges. Additionally, I am seeking the most effective method for labeling, given that a note may contain multiple labels.

**Additional Information:**
My primary goal is to maximize accuracy in predicting customer request labels. The dataset is quite large, with 3 million observations, and I have access to significant computational resources.

**Question**:
Has anyone here worked on a similar project involving the classification of customer requests with varying description lengths and the challenge of multiple labels within a single note? If so, could you share your experiences and any insights regarding the choice of algorithms or approaches?

Comment: Given this is an English language website, it would probably be more useful to provide translations of the text in your table so people can understand what you are trying to explain about your data.